# Hiding repeated totals in a ROLLUP

Tags: sql-server

I need the rows that have lines over them to not show up. Is there a way to make the rollup only show at the bottom?

[image]

Comment: How is that result set being generated? That is, what does the query look like?

Comment: Looks like you need `GROUPING SETS`. Please add your current query, along with sample data (as `CREATE TABLE` `INSERT` statements) and expected results

Comment: Please do not use images for code or data, paste them in as text instead. Images are only for things that cannot be represented as text. Please add your current query as well as sample data. It's also unclear which values are actually `NULL` and which are blank `''`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the function `GROUPING()` which tells us at what level the grouping is taking place to determine which rows are returned.
We don't have your data but here is an example on dbFiddle that you can adapt.
The first query is like I imagine your current query to be and returns 14 rows containing the basic group by totals , subtotals and the total. In the second we have add a condition which eliminates the subtotals.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE sales(
>     productLine varchar(20),
>     orderYear int,
>     orderValue int) ;
> ```

> ```
> insert into sales values
> ('Motor cycles ',2003,5072.71),
> ('Motor cycles ',2004,4301.15),
> ('Motor cycles ',2005,5971.35),
> ('Planes ',2005,4018),
> ('Trains ',2005,3774),
> ('Trains ',2003,2770.95),
> ('Trains ',2004,2819.28),
> ('Trucks and Buses ',2003,5571.8),
> ('Trucks and Buses ',2004,4615.64),
> ('Trucks and Buses ',2005,1603.2),
> ('Vintage Cers ',2004,8124.98),
> ('Vintage Cers ',2003,4080),
> ('Vintage Cers ',2005,6295.03);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     orderYear,
>     productLine, 
>     SUM(orderValue) totalOrderValue,
>     GROUPING(orderYear),
>     GROUPING(productLine)
> FROM
>     sales
> GROUP BY 
>     orderYear,
>     productline
> WITH ROLLUP;
> ```

> ```
> orderYear | productLine       | totalOrderValue | (No column name) | (No column name)
> --------: | :---------------- | --------------: | ---------------: | ---------------:
>      2003 | Motor cycles      |            5072 |                0 |                0
>      2003 | Trains            |            2770 |                0 |                0
>      2003 | Trucks and Buses  |            5571 |                0 |                0
>      2003 | Vintage Cers      |            4080 |                0 |                0
>      2003 | null              |           17493 |                0 |                1
>      2004 | Motor cycles      |            4301 |                0 |                0
>      2004 | Trains            |            2819 |                0 |                0
>      2004 | Trucks and Buses  |            4615 |                0 |                0
>      2004 | Vintage Cers      |            8124 |                0 |                0
>      2004 | null              |           19859 |                0 |                1
>      2005 | Motor cycles      |            5971 |                0 |                0
>      2005 | Planes            |            4018 |                0 |                0
>      2005 | Trains            |            3774 |                0 |                0
>      2005 | Trucks and Buses  |            1603 |                0 |                0
>      2005 | Vintage Cers      |            6295 |                0 |                0
>      2005 | null              |           21661 |                0 |                1
>      null | null              |           59013 |                1 |                1
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     orderYear,
>     productLine, 
>     SUM(orderValue) totalOrderValue,
>     GROUPING(orderYear),
>     GROUPING(productLine)
> FROM
>     sales
> GROUP BY 
>     orderYear,
>     productline
>
> WITH ROLLUP
> HAVING GROUPING(OrderYear) = GROUPING(productLine);
> ```

> ```
> orderYear | productLine       | totalOrderValue | (No column name) | (No column name)
> --------: | :---------------- | --------------: | ---------------: | ---------------:
>      2003 | Motor cycles      |            5072 |                0 |                0
>      2003 | Trains            |            2770 |                0 |                0
>      2003 | Trucks and Buses  |            5571 |                0 |                0
>      2003 | Vintage Cers      |            4080 |                0 |                0
>      2004 | Motor cycles      |            4301 |                0 |                0
>      2004 | Trains            |            2819 |                0 |                0
>      2004 | Trucks and Buses  |            4615 |                0 |                0
>      2004 | Vintage Cers      |            8124 |                0 |                0
>      2005 | Motor cycles      |            5971 |                0 |                0
>      2005 | Planes            |            4018 |                0 |                0
>      2005 | Trains            |            3774 |                0 |                0
>      2005 | Trucks and Buses  |            1603 |                0 |                0
>      2005 | Vintage Cers      |            6295 |                0 |                0
>      null | null              |           59013 |                1 |                1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=8e576a090b1b5aaff97c5da68cd5f728)*